# I have created a table in HTML by using JavaScript but 2 functions I have connected to two buttons stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, html-table

I have created a table in HTML with information in it by doing like this:

```
var tab = document.querySelector("table");
for (var obj of death_row) {
    var row = `<tr><td>${obj.first_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.last_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.age_at_execution}</td>
         <td>${obj.weight}</td>
         <td>${obj.height}</td></tr>`;
    tab.innerHTML += row;
}
```

I have created two buttons called "metric" and "imperial" and when the user clicks on them, the values in height and weight has to change to metric values (default table is showing imperial values). The code I have written for the metric button looks as so:

```
//Changes the height and weight values to metric values when clicking on "metric"-button. 

document.getElementById("metric").onclick = function() {
var tab = document.querySelector("table");
for (var obj of death_row) {
    var row = `<tr><td>${obj.first_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.last_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.age_at_execution}</td>
         <td>${((obj.weight)/2.2046).toFixed(1)}</td>
         <td>${(((Number(obj.height[0])*12*2.54) + (Number(obj.height[3])*2.54))/100).toFixed(2)}</td></tr>`;
    tab.innerHTML += row;
 }
};

//Changes the values back to imperial values when user clicks on the 'imperial' button

document.getElementById("imperial").onclick = function() {
 var tab = document.querySelector("table");
 for (var obj of death_row) {
    var row = `<tr><td>${obj.first_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.last_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.age_at_execution}</td>
         <td>${obj.weight}</td>
         <td>${obj.height}</td></tr>`;
    tab.innerHTML += row;
 }
};
```

The code when clicking the imperial-button is the same as the first piece of code I posted above as the default values is imperial. The problem is that they wont work together. They work individually if I out-comment the others and I can't really seem to be able to identify the problem, so I was hoping one of you would be able to :) Also, when I Add these adjustments to the obj.height:

```
${(((Number(obj.height[0])*12*2.54) + (Number(obj.height[3])*2.54))/100).toFixed(2)}
```

I seem to lose a lot of data in the table, which I find very weird as I lose no data by adding the "/2.2046).toFixed(1)" adjustment to the weight object.. Maybe some of you have better luck at seeing through my mistakes:)
Thank you very much:)

Comment: So you have the line as shown (`document.getElementById("metric").onclick = function() {`) and you have some other line, not shown, like `document.getElementById("imperial").onclick = function() {`?

Are you sure you didn't accidentally assign the onclick to "metric" twice?

Also, what does "they wont work together" mean exactly?  What happens if they are both connected? Nothing at all?  Wrong results?

Comment: you can create a single function that calculates both values on page loads and with buttons you only display each value.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and include more code so we can see it all.  For example I can't tell where `death_row` or `myArray` come from.

As @pitinca says, you should also group this code into a function and call it 3 times, rather than having 3 copies of it.

Comment: Still not clear on what "works" and "doesn't work" mean.  I assume "works" means "populates the table", but instead of "doesn't work", it's best to say exactly what you see.  For example "the table is empty" or "the table doesn't change".  Also, check in the browser console for any reported errors and include them.

One thing that's suspect is the code `tab.innerHTML += row;`. That keeps on adding to the table and not resetting it.  Maybe that's what "doesn't work" means :-) .  Before you start adding rows, try setting `tab.innerHTML = "";` to reset it.

Comment: I'm sure it's something that would be easy to solve if I could see everything.  I think your best bet at this point is to create a demo of the problem (even with hard-coded fake data instead of 600 lines) at https://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/ and the post a link to the live demo here.

Answer (score 0):

The codepen helped immensely!  I mentioned looking at the console output at one point.  That's critically important because it's telling you what went wrong, [so make sure you know how to see it](https://kb.mailster.co/how-can-i-open-the-browsers-console/).  In codepen its at the bottom left as well, and there's a red exclamation mark in the JS showing that an error is present.  When I hit the Metric button I see:

> TypeError: obj.height is null

That's because some of your data has null for width or height instead of the value you're expecting, so it "crashes" and just stops at whatever row caused the problem.  That's why some rows disappeared.

Two fixes I see:

- Fix your data so that the values don't have null in them
- Make the code more robust so it doesn't crash on invalid data (this is always preferable for any program).

For the second option, you can fix the code like this:

```
function MetricValues() { 
    var tab = document.querySelector("table");
    tab.innerHTML = "";
    for (var obj of death_row) {
        var height = obj.height || "0' 0\"";
        var row = `<tr><td>${obj.first_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.last_name}</td>
         <td>${obj.age_at_execution}</td>
         <td>${((obj.weight)/2.2046).toFixed(1)}</td>
         <td>${(((Number(height[0])*12*2.54) + (Number(height[3])*2.54))/100).toFixed(2)}</td></tr>`;
        tab.innerHTML += row;
    }
};
```

Using a temporary variable `var height = obj.height || "0' 0\"";` which defaults to **0' 0"** fixes the crash.
BTW you definitely should [read up on functions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_function.asp).

Comment: Bonus problem 1: Your table headers disappear when you hit a button because they are not included in the `innerHTML`.  A problem for another day!

Comment: Bonus problem 2: Your height conversion has a bug because it's only looking at the 4th character for inches. That means **5' 1"** is treated the same as **5' 10"**. Also a problem for another day.